# SVN - How can I set an ignore pattern for an entire repository/team?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to set an ignore pattern for the whole repository, or check in an ignore file along with the code itself?

Otherwise, all devs current and future have to synchronize their ignore patterns via email, and there's always people that don't do it.

Edit as a response to AI G's answer below.

> And it's worth noting again that, unlike the
>   global-ignores option, the patterns found in the svn:ignore property
>   apply only to the directory on which that property is set, and not to
>   any of its subdirectories. The svn:ignore property is a good way to
>   tell Subversion to ignore files that are likely to be present in every
>   user's working copy of that directory, such as compiler output ...
>
> Subversion 1.8 provides a more powerful version of the svn:ignore
>   property, the svn:global-ignores property. Like the svn:ignore
>   property, svn:global-ignores can only be set on a directory and
>   contains file patterns Subversion uses to determine ignorable
>   objects.[21] These ignore patterns are also appended to any patterns
>   defined in the global-ignores runtime configuration option together
>   with any svn:ignore defined patterns. Unlike svn:ignore however, the
>   svn:global-ignores property is inheritable [22] and applies to all
>   paths under the directory on which the property is set, not just the
>   immediate children of the directory.

Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the ignore pattern to the head of repository. Each dev will get it when they check out the repo. In v1.8 you can;

`svn propset svn:global-ignores *.ext`

Check out the [docs on svn:ignore here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've quoted the documentation. If I just check-out master, sit in the root of the repo and do `svn propset svn:global-ignores *.ext` then that'll do the trick all the way down, like a `.gitignore` in the root?

Comment: It should! We do this in our Repos. You can safely test it out; add the property (but don't commit!) and see if it does what you need.

Comment: I had to take the tick away, sorry. From all I'm reading, `svn:ignore` only applies to the directory on which it is set. The `sv:global-ignores` is the recursive one. I'm still testing...

Comment: Yep, `svn:global-ignores` is the way to go in 1.8+